# Populating dynamic redirect in landing pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, smart-capture

We have a large survey which I have divided into 3 forms. On completion of each  smart capture form I am trying to append some personalised elements so they get picked up in the next form so we can join all the answers to the same person.

In the body of each page I have the following declared variables which are working:

```
%%[
  var @CRM_ID, @GROUP, @EMAIL_ADDRESS
  set @CRM_ID = RequestParameter("CRM_ID")
  set @GROUP = RequestParameter("GROUP")
  set @EMAIL_ADDRESS = RequestParameter("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
]%%
```

In the submission redirect URL however I have tired all the following without joy so can anyone help?

**Try 1**

```
%%=TreatAsContent(Lookup('APAC_HKG_SURVEY_201907','CRM_ID','EMAIL_ADDRESS',@EMAIL_ADDRESS))=%%
```

**try 2**

```
http://cloud.info.timeout.com/survey2_readership2019?EMAIL_ADDRESS=(%%=TreatAsContent(Lookup('APAC_HKG_SURVEY_201907','EMAIL_ADDRESS','EMAIL_ADDRESS',@EMAIL_ADDRESS))=%%)&CRM_ID=(%%=TreatAsContent(Lookup('APAC_HKG_SURVEY_201907','CRM_ID','EMAIL_ADDRESS',@EMAIL_ADDRESS))=%%)"
```

**Try 3**

```
%%=TreatAsContent(concat("http://cloud.info.timeout.com/survey2_readership2019?, 'EMAIL_ADDRESS=', @EMAIL_ADDRESS, '?CRM_ID=', @CRM_ID, '"')=%%
```

**Try 4**

```
https://cloud.info.timeout.com/survey_readership201907c?EMAIL_ADDRESS=(%%EMAIL_ADDRESS%%)&CRM_ID=(%%CRM_ID%%)
```

This sits in the smart capture form and is triggered on form submission. The full SFMC smart capture script related to this is:

```html
<script id="smartcapture-script-qs33bgfumr">
    var scFormLoaded = function () {
        window.ScForm.init({
            "gearID": "qs33bgfumr",
            "smartCaptureFormID": 215,
            "sourceKey": "2FE6EB4B-A0E0-46AB-8A46-BE365F2047D1",
            "source": "dataExtension",
            "triggeredSend": "",
            "confirmationMessage": "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">\n\t<br />\n\t<br />\n\t<br />\n\tThank you for your submission.</div>",
            "buttonText": "NEXT",
            "formStyling": {
                "background-color": "transparent",
                "margin-top": "0px",
                "margin-right": "0px",
                "margin-bottom": "0px",
                "margin-left": "0px",
                "padding-top": "0px",
                "padding-right": "0px",
                "padding-bottom": "0px",
                "padding-left": "0px",
                "text-align": "left"
            },
            "fieldStyling": {
                "width": "200px"
            },
            "buttonStyling": {
                "background-color": "#FF0000",
                "border-color": "#FF0000",
                "border-radius": "3px",
                "border-style": "solid",
                "-webkit-border-radius": "3px",
                "-moz-border-radius": "3px",
                "color": "#FFFFFF",
                "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                "font-size": "16px",
                "line-height": "normal",
                "padding": "10px"
            },
            "onSubmitShouldGotoUrl": true,
            "onSubmitGotoUrlType": 2,
            "onSubmitGotoUrl": "THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PUT THE REDIRECT URL"
        });
    };
    window.appDomain = window.appDomain || '<ctrl:eval>Platform.Variable.GetValue("@appDomain")||""</ctrl:eval>';
    window.contentDetail = window.contentDetail || <ctrl: eval>Platform.Variable.GetValue('@contentDetail')||{}</ctrl: eval >;
    if (!window.ScForm || !window.ScForm.init) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var id = 'smartcapture-formjs-script';
        var script = document.getElementById(id);
        var domain = window.appDomain;
        var el;
        if (!script) {
            if (domain) {
                domain = '//' + domain;
            }
            el = document.createElement('script');
            el.async = true;
            el.id = id;
            el.src = domain + '/CloudPages/lib/smartcapture-formjs.js';
            el.onload = scFormLoaded;
            head.appendChild(el);
        } else {
            if (script.addEventListener) {
                script.addEventListener('load', scFormLoaded);
            } else if (script.attachEvent) {
                script.attachEvent('onload', scFormLoaded);
            }
        }
    } else {
        scFormLoaded();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to redirect to a page containing values of your ampscript-variables you just need to use the Concat- and V(alue)-function to build your URL and the Redirect-function to perform the redirect.

```
%%[
    Redirect(Concat("https://cloud.info.timeout.com/survey_readership201907c?EMAIL_ADDRESS=", V(@EMAIL_ADDRESS), "&CRM_ID=", V(@CRM_ID)))
]%%
```

Your tries 1-3 suggest you try adding data from data extensions as well. If that is the case I suggest pulling the data to a variable beforehand and doing the same as mentioned in my code example above.

As per your comments you just like to output the URL somewhere. Therefore the redirect function isn't needed and the following should work:

```
%%=V(Concat("https://cloud.info.timeout.com/survey_readership201907c?EMAIL_ADDRESS=", V(@EMAIL_ADDRESS), "&CRM_ID=", V(@CRM_ID)))=%%
```

**Further documentation:**

- [Redirect function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirect.htm)
- [V function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/v.htm)
- [Concat function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm)

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work. Instead the page URL now loads the 2nd page of the form instead of the first.
I think the issue is that the redirect is on submission of the smart capture form which is in a script. I don't think you can add ampscript inside a script.
Do you know any way around this please?

Comment: I guess you'd have to rephrase your question then as you asked for a dynamic redirect in a landing page. My proposed solution does exactly that. Please describe all the assets you use, provide all the code and describe the process as a whole. This would make it easier to find the solution you are searching for.

Comment: I've added the full standard smart capture submission script above so you can see where the redirect is being placed. All suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Hope this works out for you! FYI: Please check out the formatting options stackexchange provides for sourcecode as the version you posted wasn't readable at all.